# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I've been searching around for a while now but can't seem to find the answer.

I'm using paperclip and postgresql database to upload and store files.

The error I am getting is :

`Errno::EACCES in DocumentsController#create`

`Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /documents`

And the error code is specifically referring to this section in the documents controller:

```
def create
    @document = current_user.documents.build(documents_params)

    if @document.save
        redirect_to @document
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

I recently switched my database from sqlite to postgresql and it is working perfectly fine online (I have uploaded it with heroku), just not in development.

Also, I am able to edit and update documents that have been uploaded already in development, just not able to upload any.

Are there any config files or something that I need to modify to grand permission for `@ dir_s_mkdir`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Finally I managed to fix this problem.*

- Because I had modified my database to use **PostgreSQL** with Heroku I needed to also modify my `Document` model, to accomodate for both production and development environments.
- I also had to change the `:url` that the document object was assigning to in *development*. The updated `:url` became:

  ```
  :url => "/system/documents/pdfs/:id/:basename.:extension"
  ```

---

Below is the updated `document.rb` model (for the `paperclip` section):

```
if Rails.env.development?
    has_attached_file :pdf, :use_timestamp => false,
                      :url => "/system/documents/pdfs/:id/:basename.:extension",
                      :path => ":rails_root/public/system/documents/pdfs/:id/:basename.:extension"
    validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => ["application/pdf","application/vnd.ms-excel",     
         "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
         "application/msword", 
         "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
         "text/plain"]

else
    has_attached_file :pdf, :use_timestamp => false
    validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => ["application/pdf","application/vnd.ms-excel",     
         "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
         "application/msword", 
         "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
         "text/plain"]
end
```

Many answers I referred to were saying to use either:

```
sudo chown -R username app_path
/* or */
chmod -R 777 PATH_TO_APP/uploads 
/* or */
chmod -R 777 PATH_TO_APP/tmp
```

Although changing ownership of a file/folder is not a good option, as it sets every file as executable, readable, and writeable by anyone.